# Write to file with nccurses

Tags: python, redirect, output, ncurses

I'm attempting to create a menu system with ncurses to configure the ip address of a Ubuntu box.  I've taken the example found here:

http://tuxradar.com/content/code-project-build-ncurses-ui-python

The program successfully prompts for all information, but where I run into issues is when attempting to write to /etc/network/interfaces.

Code Snippet

```
screen.addstr(4, 4, "1 - Configure Static IP Address")
.....
staticIP = get_param("Enter the IP address")
system("echo 'address ' + staticIP >> /etc/network/interfaces")
```

This is successfully writing to the file, but it's writing the literal text without using the value of the variable.

```
address staticIP
```

The last line was originally "execute_cmd", but I discovered that "system" seems to do the same thing without prompting after each line is executed.

I'm a python/ncurses newb...and pro tips out there are much appreciated!  If there's a better option, I'm open to that as well...not tied to ncurses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have the command wrongly escaped. It should read:

```
system("echo 'address '" + staticIP + " >> /etc/network/interfaces")
```

Else, you are sending the params `address`, `+` and `staticIP` to `echo` command.